# Pushing to stack reference to the class begin generated with ASM

Tags: java, code-generation, bytecode

I'm using ASM Java library to generate a class `X` from scratch. Inside one of the static methods of this class I need to push a reference to `X.class`. Since there isn't yet a `X.class` I can't use `visitLdcInsn`. Is there a way to do it?

Well, it's possible (and I'm currently using it) to generate the following code `(new X().getClass())`, but I'm sure that's not the cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With generated code you usually don't need to push the class onto the stack.  Anything you can do with a method call is usually available in byte code.

Say you have to call a method with a class, you can push it onto the stack whether it exists or not.

Something I use is the ASMifier.  This is useful because you can start with a class which compiles and does what you want as a template and get it to dump all the code needed to recreate the class.  This means you don't really need to write most of the code yourself.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    ASMifierClassVisitor cv = new ASMifierClassVisitor(new PrintWriter(System.out));
    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader("X");
    cr.accept(cv, 0);
  }
}

class X {
  {
    System.out.println("Inside class "+X.class);
  }
}
```

prints

```
// lots of code
mv.visitLdcInsn(Type.getType("LX;"));
// more code.
```

Comment: The problem is that: inside this static method I'm generating I need to call another method using 'X.class' as one of its arguments, so I need to push X.class onto the stack

Comment: I have added an example.  Unless you mean you want to use a static method of `X`

Comment: I'm sorry, I was reading before you completed it. I guess Type.getType("LX;") is exactly what I need. And I will take a look at the ASMifier, I guess it can simplify a lot of things here. THANKS!

Comment: In one project, I used it to generate over 1000 lines of code I didn't need to write. ;) I started with a "template" which has every combination I want to support and then I generalised it after using this tool.